# If Jaden bets his friend Jordan $5 that he can roll a 4 in 3 tries with one die. Is this a fair bet?

Tags: probability

Jaden bets his friend Jordan $5 that he can roll a 4 in 3 tries with one die. Is this a fair bet?

The above problem is taken from this website: https://www.mathworksheetsland.com/tests/HSstatssampleversion2.pdf
question 17

My solution is it is not a fair bet for Jaden, since the probability of Jaden winning is (1/6) + (5/6)(1/6) + (5/6)(5/6)(1/6) which is equal to approximately 42 percent, and the probability for Jaden losing is (5/6)^3 which approximate to 58 percent. However the solution provided from the source website is it is a fair bet for Jaden with the following explanation:

"The probability that Jaden will roll a 4 in 3 tries with one die is: 1/6+1/6+1/6 =3/6=1/2 or a 50%
probability he will, therefore it is a fair bet."

The solution provided doesn't make sense to me. Is the solution provided wrong? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The solution provided is *very* wrong.  You are correct.  Letting $A$ be the event that the first result is a four, $B$ that the second result is a four, and $C$ that the third result is, the author appears to be attempting to use $Pr(A\cup B\cup C)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)\color{red}{-Pr(A\cap B)-Pr(A\cap C)-Pr(B\cap C)+Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}$ and has neglected to take into consideration the parts in red.

Comment: An easy way to remember this is consider flipping three fair coins.  The probability of getting at least one head on the three coins is obviously not $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1.5$ because this is greater than $1$ and could not possibly be a probability.

Comment: To reiterate the point., you should remember that $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$ if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=0$ which for example occurs when $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive or disjoint events.  Similarly $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$ occurs if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  It is unfortunately common to see people think you can *always* add and *always* multiply events which is simply not the case.  You may only add or multiply probabilities like this in very specific and restrictive circumstances.

Comment: @JMoravitz More tailored to this example, we could also ask what would happen if Jaden rolled 6 times, would Jaden win 100% of the time? And then, of course, when we move to more than 6 times it becomes absurd.

Answer (score 2):

It is a fair bet if Jaden rolls three times and gets paid for each $3$ that he rolls.  The website is computing the expected number of $3$s that are rolled, which is $\frac 12$.  This would include getting paid $10$ when two $3$s come up and $15$ when three do.

The wording of the bet seems to be that Jaden stops rolling if he gets a $3$ or in any case only gets paid once for a set of rolls no matter how many $3$s are rolled.  In that case your analysis is correct and Jaden has a losing bet.